# How does changing the training/test ratio, affect the RSE ans R2 metrics?

Tags: machine-learning, multiple-regression, train-test-split

If I change the training/test ratio from 90/10 to say 80/20 or 70/30, how does that affect the RSE and R2 metrics? I see changes in the results of the RSE and R2 when I implement the model, but I cannot grasp the underlying reasoning behind those.

For a 90/10 split (Linear regression model on the Boston Housing Dataset) I had the following results:

RSE for training = 0.02577413485637635 |||

RSE for testing = 0.0782435232487672

R2 for training = 0.7612428866092609 |||

R2 for testing = 0.7754233967070088.

For a 70/30 split I had the following:

RSE for training= 0.031168053531247658 |||

RSE for testing= 0.03775631124698821 |||

R2 for training= 0.7437862095331289 |||

R2 for testing= 0.8063900607780959

and for a 50/50 split I had these:

RSE for training= 0.038324514690667257 |||

RSE for testing= 0.03136868881928254 |||

R2 for training= 0.7353321015108675

R2 for testing= 0.7832763784168615.

What do those differences show overall?

Answer (score 0):

Boston housing dataset is a small one (506 samples [this link](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Edelve/data/boston/bostonDetail.html) says), so you can certainly have variability. Pick a decent split and repeat your experiments several times. In the end, report the mean and std of the performance metric.